# Offline Address Book Not Replicating Between Exchange 2010 and Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003, replication, public-folders

I have recently installed Exchange 2010 in our Exchange 2003 (SP2) environment. So far everything has been great, until we noticed creating new users does not populate the OAB for people still logging into Exchange 2003.

For instance, my mailbox has been moved to Exchange 2010 and I can see the new user in my OAB. However, my coworker, whose mailbox is still on Exchange 2003, cannot see the new user in his OAB.

The OAB is being published by the Exchange 2010 server and set to replicate to Web folders as well as Public folders. It is replicating all versions of the OAB (2,3 and 4).

I have open the Public Folders tool on the Exchange 2010 server and I see the same hierarchy exists on both the Exchange 2003 and also Exchange 2010 server.

I have rebuilt the OAB on Exchange 2010 and then went into the public folders and did an Update now. I receive no errors. Both Exchange 2010 and Exchange 2003 are set to replicate on the OAB.

I'd greatly appreciate any help offered--this is driving me nuts.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Outlook are you running? and are you able to see new users if you disable caching?

Comment: Do you have test if new contact is present in owa?